# Kind of SUMPRODUCT that makes UNION operation instead of INTERSECTION

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need a a combination of some formulas that makes the same thing as `SUMPRODUCT` formula, but `SUMPRODUCT` inherits intersection principle, while I need the union principle.

Here is the structure of my data:
I have multiple columns with "1" as a flag. 
Columns divided into groups of personnel like: `Top management`, `Middle management`, `Workers`.
Each group has 3 subcat: `Salary increase`, `No change`, `Salary decrease`.
While rows represent different companies.

I need to count number of companies that have `Salary increase` \ `No change` \ `Salary decrease` in at least 1 personnel group so that if `company A` has `Salary increase` for `Workers`, then the whole company is thought to be going to increase salary.

[image]

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of a sample of your data? I feel like that would be helpful.

Comment: Here is the capture of current structure:
http://i.stack.imgur.com/7XPoG.png

Different shades of green  - are my 5 groups, each having 3 subcategories. Yellow area on the right represents summary on that subcategories and finds if it least 1 subcategory in any group has a flag. After this is done, cell T1 counts "Selected" and represent that number as % of total companies.

Comment: @Shurov: post an image of your data, or provide a link to your data sheet structure.

Comment: @AHC: please find it in my previous comment

Comment: I feel that the formula should look smth like `=SUMPRODUCT(IF(OR(B2:B9="Selected",E2:E9="Selected",H2:H9="Selected",K2:K9="Selected",N2:N9="Selected"),1,0))`
However, I doubt that such ranges in `OR` function will work. I will try and play with it now

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand correctly. What I think you are saying is that you want a formula to return a count of 1 for each company that has a salary increase, and you want to do 3 formulas so you have the count of increase, decrease and no change? If so, here is the formula for increase (assuming the first comlumn in each group is "increase").

=SUMPRODUCT(OR(B2:B9 = "Selected", E2:E9="Selected", H2:H9="Selected", K2:K9="Sel‌​ected", N2:N9="Selected") * 1)